# 2 user controls on registered on one aspx page not validating validation properly

Tags: asp.net

I have 2 user controls on registered on one aspx page.
 UserControl1 us having   one text box with require field and one submit button.
UserControl2 is also having  one text box with requirefiled and save button.
Expected o/p is-
When I am clicking on any button out of 2(submit or save). Then only related text boxof that user control should be validate.
But the error is
Both text boxes are validate.

Please help me .

Comment: actually i wrote "Page.Validate()" function on button_click events.I think that might be giving problem..

Answer (score 2):

Set the [ValidationGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424.aspx) properties to limit which fields get validated when the buttons are pressed.

So for example, if these were contained within the first user control:

```
<asp:requiredfieldvalidator id="NameValidator"
  controltovalidate="NameTextBox"
  validationgroup="UserControlOne"
  errormessage="required"
  runat="Server" />

 <asp:button id="Submit" 
  text="Submit" 
  causesvalidation="true"
  validationgroup="UserControlOne"
  runat="Server" />
```

Clicking the "Submit" button would only cause the validators that have `UserControlOne` specified as the ValidationGroup to validate.

Edit: When you call `Page.Validate()` you are validating every group on the page. Call the overloaded `Page.Validate(validationGroup)` to validate a specific one. e.g. `Page.Validate("UserControlOne")`

Comment: There is a separate validation group for these 2 user controls having different names. Then also problem is still there.

Comment: @mangesh, post your code so that we can all have a look at it. Have you specified the validation group on the RequiredFieldValidators as well as the buttons?

Comment: actually i wrote "Page.Validate()" function on button_click events.I think that might be giving problem.please let me know......